# Manually Installing Python Libraries

Tags: python, pip, version, tabula

I need to use the tabula library version 0.9.2.

When I type the following, everything works fine:

```
python -m pip install tabula
```

I need to use a specific version of tabula. When I type python -m pip install tabula==0.9.2, I get this error message:

```
Collecting tabula==0.9.2
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tabula==0.9.2 (from ve
rsions: 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.0.5)
No matching distribution found for tabula==0.9.2
```

So, I am now attempting to install the tabula library manually; however, I have never done this before.

When I go [here](https://github.com/tabulapdf/tabula/releases?after=oldUI) and download

> tabula-jar-0.9.2.zip

these do not look like the files I normally have when I install a module using pip. Is there something that I need to know or do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tabula` is a Java library. You need to download the [python wrapper](https://github.com/chezou/tabula-py) with:

```
pip install tabula-py
```

or

```
python -m pip install tabula-py
```

Comment: When I do that, it says "successfully installed tabula-py-1.2.0. This should work without any problem for version 0.9.2?

Comment: you can attempt to download the same version as you were doing before: `pip install tabula-py==0.9.2`

Comment: "No matching distribution found for tabula-py 0.9.2"

Comment: I cannot find any information about which wrapper matches which java library version... You should try using 1.2.0 and see what happens. Otherwise you can try some other versions: https://pypi.org/project/tabula-py/#history

Comment: So weird, like I know it exists, but it doesn't look for that specific version.

Comment: Question: Whenever pip is used, is that ALWAYS the location where it looks to install modules? How do you know? I have an idea . . .